# Singly-Linked List Doesn't Add to Beginning Correctly

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, structure, nodes

I am attempting to sort student records (SRECs) into  a singly-linked list.  The record comparison here is by the student's last name.  The code below compares correctly, but when it places the new record at the list's start, it overwrites the second record.  That is, the second record later prints as the exact same record.

Help?
Thanks in advance!

```
/*Insert and sort new SREC into each list*/
        if(insert != NULL)
        {
            insert -> next = NULL;

            prev = NULL;
            current = listStart;


            while(current != NULL && strcmp(insert->lname, current->lname) > 0)
            {
                prev = current;
                current = current -> next;
            }

                    if(prev == NULL) /*This is to place the new record at the start of the list*/
            {
                        insert -> next = listStart;
                listStart = insert;
                    }
            else
            {
                prev -> next = insert;
                insert -> next = current;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Insertion failed\n");
        }

    return listStart;
```

Comment: I don't see any obvious problem here. Could you provide a minimal compilable example (with `main()`) which exhibits the problem?

Comment: the only probem i can think of in this case, that your call to the function is incorrect. Make sure you call it like `listStart = whateverInsertFuncNamed(listStart,insert);`

Answer (score 0):

The comparison is reversed :

```
strcmp(insert->lname, current->lname) > 0
```

Should be :

```
strcmp(insert->lname, current->lname) < 0
```

Or :

```
strcmp(current->lname, insert->lname) > 0
```

One example, if `current->lname` is `"b"` and `insert->lname` is `"a"`, `strcmp` will perform `'a' - 'b'` (result: `-1`). Since you're testing the opposite condition, `insert` goes after `current`.